# How to properly display all data from a Sqlite database into a ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am attempting to access all of the the Data I have persisted into a sqlite db. The database is full of Quarter objects. I want to display them all using a ListView.Builder. Only issue it that I'm not exactly understanding the proper way how in my case. What I currently have errors out with the error `type 'QueryRow' is not a subtype of 'List<dynamic>'`  I will mark where the IDE says this error is coming from. Any help is appreciated with showing me what I'm doing wrong and correcting me! Thanks!

This is what I currently have. I've marked where the error I detailed above is supposedly coming from

```
class ChangeQuarter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChangeQuarterState createState() => _ChangeQuarterState();
}

class _ChangeQuarterState extends State<ChangeQuarter> {
  Future<void> _future;
  static const Color greycolor = Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 10);

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(95.0),
          child: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides leading widget
            flexibleSpace: QuarterAppBar(),
          ),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
            future: QuarterDBProvider.quarterDB.getQuarter(),
            initialData: List(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                    );
                  }
              }
=> ERROR LOCATION   List quarter = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                        final quarter = snapshot.data[index];
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                          child: Card(
                            color: (index % 2 == 0) ? greycolor : Colors.white,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                                      child: Text(snapshot.data[index].quarter,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20,
                                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                              color: Colors.blue),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );

            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically saying you are trying to use a `List<dynamic>` where you should be using a `QueryRow`. The  `QuarterDBProvider.quarterDB.getQuarter()` returns a `QueryRow` and you are declaring the Future builder like this: `FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>` whereas it should be `FutureBuilder<QueryRow>`. Also you should correct the `List quarter = snapshot.data;` into `QueryRow quarter = snapshot.data;`.

If you need any further help please let me know on what to do with the `QueryRow` but I assume you already know, because you are using SQlite

Comment: Also it is a good practice to provide a type for your List's for example: ```List<int>list = [1,2,3];```

Comment: QueryRow says it is an undefined class when I attempt to define the FutureBuilder with it or put `QueryRow quarter = snapshot.data`. Am I missing something? An Import to use QueryRow?

Comment: You might need to import SQflite library